# If Array/Table contains xyz, than redirect to its value (PHP? JS? htaccess?)

Tags: php, arrays, .htaccess, multidimensional-array

I moved approx 100 articles from my old website to a new one. I want to create a redirect in the old site's header, so if the old URL of an article would be visited, the visitor should be redirected to the new URL of that article.

However, just replacing the domain won't do the trick, as I changed the permalink of the articles. So **I would need some "database" (with arrays?) which would decide if the actual URL has a redirect in the database**, like:

```
// "the old permalink" = "the new permalink"
$urlpermalink["article-cars"] = "http://NewWebsite.com/new-cars-article";
$urlpermalink["an-article-dogs"] = "http://NewWebsite.com/new-dogs-text";
$urlpermalink["old-text-trees"] = "http://NewWebsite.com/new-blogcontent-about-trees";
```

**So for example if a visitor visits "http://OldWebsite.com/article-cars", he should be redirected to "http://NewWebsite.com/new-cars-article", because that's how the database/array says.**

And so I could something like this:

```
$visitingurl = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; // Getting the URL the visitor is on now

foreach( $urlpermalink as $value ) { // For every entry in the database/array...
    if (strpos($visitingurl, $urlpermalink) !== false) { // check if the visitingurl contains that (like "article-cars")
        // The visitor is indeed on an old URL which is in the database/array, so let's redirect him to the new URL
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header(url . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Of course this code is totally wrong, but I have almost no idea about **PHP**, so could you please help me solving this? (a **JavaScript**-solution is fine too, or **htaccess**, or whatever :) )

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this now with htaccess (I have no idea about htaccess either, just googled even more).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/article-cars/ http://NewWebsite.com/new-cars-article
RedirectMatch 301 ^/an-article-dogs/ http://NewWebsite.com/new-dogs-text
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old-text-trees/ http://NewWebsite.com/new-blogcontent-about-trees
</IfModule>
```

Is this okay this way?

Comment: Well, does it work? Then it is "okay", right?

Comment: @arkascha A working solution can still be a bad solution :) It could cause issues later, or be a problem regarding security, etc.

Comment: Sure, no statement is absolutely true and known. But how do you expect others to answer to this? We know next to nothing about your specific situation or the future. So we can only answer in general and broad terms. Redirecting requests is possible, a normal thing to do and does not by itself suddenly open obvious security issues.